# Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs

Tags: drivers, intel, firmware, microcode

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS this afternoon. Previously I mainly used Linux Mint. I've tried other Ubuntu/Debian variants and Manjaro, including Ubuntu itself. Ubuntu was my first intro into Linux, and the first time I installed and used it, I was amazed, scared and confused! Now I've gotten much used to Linux...

Anyways, on Mint the following option in the "Additional Drivers" window wasn't enabled; instead "Do not use the device" was enabled, but here on Ubuntu, as seen from the following image, I see that it's been pre-enabled.

[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wrv9.png)

Now I have a bunch of updates on my Software Updater. Among them is "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs" update...

[Software updater window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT2O3.png)

What should I do now? Do I select the "Do not use this device" option and not bother with the update? Or do I keep using the proprietary device? I've found a bunch of articles here, but as I said I don't understand all that much, rather it's really confusing! A sure-fire answer would be of great help!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So you're suggesting that I keep that option enabled and keep using the proprietary driver? And also should I update the processor microcode as in the software updater window shown in the image?

Comment: Yes to both questions is my suggestion.

Comment: But according to [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode) article, there are some warnings!

"-Installing the microcode package may cause problems on your computer. So only apply it when you experience problems with your CPU!

- Don't install microcode when the microcode package is older than your BIOS / UEFI!"

Comment: The last time the Intel Microcode firmware was updated by the Software Updater application was on August 25, 2017, so the latest Intel Microcode firmware package is probably newer than your BIOS/UEFI on that computer.

Comment: I also have to make sure that my BIOS is up to date! I know there's update available, but haven't really bothered. It's not really necessary, and sometimes BIOS update causes issues...

Comment: Often BIOS/UEFI updates **solves** issues and that's why the manufacturers do provide this after sales service. They wouldn't bother otherwise. Check the changelog for the new BIOS/UEFI version and then decide if the issues (supposedly) fixed affects you or not. If not and everything else is working as expected, leave it. Otherwise update (your tech support may tell you to do that anyway and irrespective of the issue you are reporting. Again, that's way updates exist). Use the Intel (or AMD) microcode as it provides enhancements or fixes for the CPU itself.